Get Macro to Run Based on Checkbox Trigger
I am a new Sheets, I have checked other responses on this, but I suck at coding and broke the script each time I did it - it stopped running.
Essentially, I want to add a trigger based on a checkbox in sheets to execute the script below. This copy and paste a new "project" set of cells below and ideally repeats each time the box would be ticked. I plan on having another macro run that removes completed projects to a different worksheet, but I have yet to develop this.
What can I add to get this to work via a checkbox in the sheet?
function Addproject() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B34').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B29:L33').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};

function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B39').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B34:P38').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};

function Addproject1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-5, 0, 5, 16).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}; 


Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this to provide a markdown table (you may create one with the help of this link ) or an anonymous sample spreadsheet (using this link
